# Why I am not getting value of key from json object,what am I doing wrong?

Tags: json, geojson

I am trying to get key "weather" from JSON object obj,and from that I am trying to get value of key "main" i.e Clouds. Here is my code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#getMessage").on("click", function() {

        $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=coord.lat&lon=coord.lon&APPID=b10811ac33cbff62d9facbabc293bbbf", function(json) {
          var data = JSON.stringify(json);
          var yo = "";
          var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
          $.each(obj, function() {

            yo += this['weather'][0]['main']; // Please correct here,I think here is some problem
          });

          $(".message").html(yo);
        });

      });

    });
```

The JSON object obj contains this data from which I am trying to get weather condition Clouds:

```
  {
      "coord": {
        "lon": 0.78, "lat": 0.25
      }
      ,
      "weather":[ {
        "id": 803, "main": "Clouds", "description": "broken clouds", "icon": "04d"
      }
      ],
      "base":"cmc stations",
      "main": {
        "temp": 296.934, "pressure": 1030.02, "humidity": 100, "temp_min": 296.934, "temp_max": 296.934, "sea_level": 1030.01, "grnd_level": 1030.02
      }
      ,
      "wind": {
        "speed": 5.22, "deg": 191.003
      }
      ,
      "clouds": {
        "all": 76
      }
      ,
      "dt":1468231605,
      "sys": {
        "message": 0.0047, "country": "YE", "sunrise": 1468216709, "sunset": 1468260392
      }
      ,
      "id":8282146,
      "name":"Font Al-Da'da",
      "cod":200
    }
```

Here is link to my Codepen http://codepen.io/meow414/pen/rLGkWv
The response to API call is different each time,but all the keys and format remain the same. Also if you want to have a look at the JSON object you can use:

```
$(".message").html(data);// it will show the JSON objecct from which I am trying to get data.
```

I am really not getting how to do this,please do not mark it duplicate,reading those similar questions has not helped me. Please tell me how to correct my code to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The object you are getting by calling `$.parseJSON(data);` seems to be of type `object`. It's not an array.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

So your `$.each` loop does not make sense. You should be able to access the `['weather']` key on the variable `obj`, without looping through `obj`.

Comment: Now I am using `yo+=obj.weather.main;` but still not getting any output.